# how to decompress a local drive?

Tags: sql-server, database, compression, drive

I have local drive in my system. The file system in my drive is NTFS. Some days ago I compressed my drive by disk cleanup for releasing free space.
But when I want to attached my sql database with server then it gives error that show like this but not exact

"The attachment of database is failed. Your database is compressed and it needs to decompress the database."

Answer (score 1):

Use "compact" command-line utility. Here is its documentation: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc976800.aspx

Comment: thanks to reply. I will check this and give you response